# Actionscript 3 component question

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, components

Does AS3 offer a way to customize the position of the image and text in the default `TileList` component?

*I want to make a list of preview - description pairs, where item is located to the left of the text.*

I assume this can be implemented using `DataGrid` and filling one cell with image and another with the description, but there should probably be a way to make that using `TileList`. I suspect I have to override item positioning in my own renderer, but I am not sure where to start digging.

---

Also - is there any way to render rich text (at least with **bold** / *italic* support) in those components? How should it be implemented?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create your own cell renderer that either extends [CellRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/listClasses/CellRenderer.html) or impliments [ICellRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/listClasses/ICellRenderer.html) then set your component to use it:

```
list.setStyle("cellRenderer", myCellRendererClass);
```

details can be found here:  [Adobe ActionScript 3.0 - Work with a CellRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/components/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fd4.html)